# How do I leave a WiFi network on OS X without turning AirPort off?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, ssid, airport

I'm unable to find info on how to use `networksetup` or some other tool on OS X that will allow me to disassociate/leave a WiFi network without turning off AirPort or removing the preferred networks list.

When the Mac hasn't joined any networks but WiFi is on, it is precisely in this state, but I need to know how to trigger this on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Apple includes a command line utility to change AirPort settings, called `airport`.

```
sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -z
```

The `-z` option will disassociate from any network. If you use that command often, you can link it to a directory that's in your `PATH`, for example `/usr/bin`.

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/bin/airport
```

After this, you'll only have to call:

```
airport
```